# CaptainCasa framework: The default DOF page cannot be load if there are many records in the database

Tags: java

We are using default DOF grids to present the data in the database. We are using this function out of the box and we are doing only the required xml configuration.

In some cases, the tables contain several hundred thousand records and the DOF grid does not show any data, it shows only empty page, although it has to load only 400 records (by default) on the page.

We tryed to find a configuration parameter which can be related to this behavior, but without success, and we have no more options, since we are limited to the configuration in this case.

We were not able to find any particular reason for this behavior, or any good resolution of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLease check where the performance is "burned" - from the behavior you describe it seems to be the query to the database. There are two queries which are executed: the query to get the number of items and then the query selecting the items (with some SQL querying the n top-items).

Debugging point is the class DOFJDBCPersistor method "executeQuery()". The code is quite straight forward.

Maybe in your case the querying of the number of items takes as long as querying all the items?

When debugging through your scenario: please also check the number of items that are returned within the result set processing. Maybe the DB ignores the TOP statement and returns all the items, which then would of course cause some trouble when making objects out of them. - Same location for debugging as mentioned above.

Comment: Hello @Björn, I followed your advise and I did some debugging in class DOFJDBCPersistor method "executeQuery()" as you suggest, the result is that 'DOFJdbcUtil.checkIfSQLSelectLimitIsSupported()' is returning false, and it has to return true in our case, because we are using Postgresql. After some more debug, I found out that actually we do not inialize DOFJdbcDBType properly and get the common behaviour, and not the one specific to postgrsql.

Answer (score 0):

Good... Could you just confirm that the problem now is solved?

And for all other readers: the type is set in the following way:

```
DOFJdbcUtil.instance().setDbType(...);
```